# How to calculate number of decades between two dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

There are easy ways to calculate number of days/months/years between two NSDate Objects. It can be done as follows for date( from apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html )

But I want to calculate number of decades between two NSDate objects. Any pointers?

For example 1-Jan-1970 to 5-May-1987 has two decades, that is, 1970-1979 and 1980-1989.

Comment: Just minus the larger date's years from the second and then divide by 10, then use ceiling on the result will give you how many decades.

Comment: So what's the number of decades from 1979 to 1981? And when is the end of a decade (1970 is in the decade from 1961 to 1970, 1987 in the decade from 1981 to 1990).

Answer (score 2):

@Abbath's answer will give you a value of 1 (therefore the number of whole decades between the two dates).

It sounds like you actually want the answer in your example to be 2, for the 70s and 80s even though the whole decade of the 80s is not included.

If you `ceil` the result instead of flooring it, that should give you the answer you're looking for.